# Limesurvey the link to the end of survey

Tags: jquery, limesurvey

Hy can anyone help me with limesurvey?
I have a script and whenever someone click's the button with the id in script below it should end the survey but i dont know which is the link for the end of the survey, i should replace picture2.html with the link of the end of survey.

```
$("#answer326959X5X13A5").click(function() {window.location.href='picture2.html';})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have 'endurl' in LimeSUrvey. All is done via $_POST.

Here : use quota ... like Mazi say at the forum.